# Restore mysql dump (plesk)

Tags: ubuntu, plesk

So after a server failure I decided to upgrade from Ubuntu 10.4 and plesk 11 to Ubuntu 14.04 and Plesk 12 rightaway.

Now I'm trying to restore the mysql database. I have a complete mysql dump.

**Does this dump contain previous plesk data (plesk 11)? Can I just restore the dump using mysql on command line without breaking plesk 12?**

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean users databases or Plesk psa database? In both cases you shouldn't dump/restore these databases manually. In scope of migration or upgrade Plesk process it will be done automatically. Manual dump/restore mysql Plesk databases will lead to unpredictable consequences.

Comment: I meant the complete MySQL database. However the problem is "solved" now, I had to restore the DB manually as Plesk's restore completely broke everything and my hoster's restore didn't work at all. You were right, I got a corrupt DB after manual restore, but I managed to repair it.